# Port 80 can't be opened in my computer

Tags: apache, http

First of all, i configured port 80 in my modem router which is 192.168.1.1 and in windows firewall, but although when i check it in websites that does my port 80 open or not?
I get this result: it is closed, how to solved it, call internet provider or what? does it have any other solution that u can help me

Please Help

Regards

Answer (score 1):

if your web server is installed/setup behind a router(local) you need to configure your router for port forwarding pointing to your server ip and port.. you can also enable DMZ and set to point to your server local ip address.

http://lifehacker.com/127276/geek-to-live--how-to-access-a-home-server-behind-a-routerfirewall